# Use DatabaseFactory to call Stored Procedure by passing TableType

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am getting error while trying to pass table type to Stored Procedure

Created datatable dataTableMyData with datatype name

> ```
> DataTable dataTableMyData = new DataTable("myTableType");
> ```

My code :

> ```
>  DatabaseFactory.ClearDatabaseProviderFactory();
>  DatabaseFactory.SetDatabaseProviderFactory(new DatabaseProviderFactory());
>  Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
>  DataSet dsResult = new DataSet();
>   DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sp_Save_Clue_Auto_Response"))
>   db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@myTableType", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured, dataTableMyData);
> ```

How to use the DatabaseFactory to pass table type. Please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't execute the command? Did you forget to post that in your sample?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlDatabase database = (SqlDatabase) DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("DatabaseName");
DbCommand dbCommand = database.GetStoredProcCommand("[StoredProcName]");
database.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@MyTvp",SqlDbType.Structured, table);
DataSet dataSet = database.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the best approach, but works:

```
-- Create the data type
CREATE TYPE dbo.PlantList AS TABLE 
(
    plant_code char(1) Not Null Primary Key
)
GO
```

extension method

```
public static class DatabaseExtensions
{
    public static void AddTableTypeParameter<T>(this Database database, DbCommand command, string name, string sqlType, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] members = values.First().GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(member.Name, member.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            row.ItemArray = members.Select(m => m.GetValue(value)).ToArray();
            table.Rows.Add(row); 
        }
        var parameter = new SqlParameter(name, SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            TypeName = sqlType,
            SqlValue = table
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

}
```

and call as follows:

```
database.AddTableTypeParameter(command, "@region_filter_plants", "dbo.PlantList", regionFilterPlants.Select(p => new { plant_code = p }));
```